# How can I use tailwind-css to style the active state of the Navlink(react-router-dom)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, tailwind-css, classname

I am trying to use a template literal for the className of the `Navlink` but it does not work.

This is current code:

```
className={`px-2 py-2.5 hover:bg-cprimary-300 hover:text-csecond-100 rounded-md transition ${({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-black-500"}`}
```

I tried using only the active part to check if anything else is messing with it but it still does not work.

```
className={`${({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-blue-500"}`}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am using the template literal?

It works when I use this:

```
className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-blue-500"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `className` prop takes either a string ***or*** a function callback that is passed an `isActive` prop and returns a string or undefined.

See [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean; }) => string | undefined); // <--
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean; }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Use the callback function to accept the `isActive` prop and return a string containing the CSS classes you want to be applied.

```
className={({ isActive }) => [
    "px-2 py-2.5",
    "hover:bg-cprimary-300 hover:text-csecond-100",
    "rounded-md transition",
    isActive ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-black-500"
  ].join(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.   className={`px-2 py-2.5 hover:bg-cprimary-300 hover:text-csecond-100 rounded-md transition ${isActive ? "bg-red-500": "bg-black-500"}` }